# How can I create a "clear queue" command in discord py

Tags: python, discord

I've been programming a discord bot using DiscordUtils and discord.py for a time now, and I want to create a command to wipe the current queue. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

```
@commands.command(help="Shows all the songs in the current queue")
async def queue(ctx, arg=None):
myconnectedtrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
if arg == "clear":
    songs = f"{f', '.join([song.name for song in player.current_queue()])}"
    list_of_songs = songs.split(",")
    no_o_songs = len(list_of_songs)
    for i in list_of_songs:
        await player.remove_from_queue(i)
    return
```

This is an extremely crude attempt of trying to do this, it doesn't work for probably obvious reasons. This was the best I could do though. What I am wondering is if there is a better way to do this that I'm missing out on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python method called `.clear()`. I'm assuming you're using a list to store the queue data (I would recommend learning some JSON or SQLite due to them being more reliable). Instead of seeing how long the list is and running a for loop, you can do `list_of_songs.clear()`.